# PHP MYSQL insert command doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am struggling with this piece of code. Why doesn't it work? It does receive the variables, but the sql command doesn't work.

```
 if ($action=='create')
  {

  $Surname=$_REQUEST['Surname'];
  $Name=$_REQUEST['Name'];
  $Fathername=$_REQUEST['Fathername'];
  $Dateofbirth=$_REQUEST['Dateofbirth'];
  $Afm=$_REQUEST['Afm'];
  $Landline=$_REQUEST['landline'];
  $Mobile=$_REQUEST['Mobile'];
  $Address=$_REQUEST['Adrs'];
  $Addressnum=$_REQUEST['Adrsnm'];
  $Location=$_REQUEST['Location'];
  $ZIP=$_REQIEST['Zip'];
  $Bankaccount=$_REQUEST['Bankaccount'];

$createuser=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Customers` (`Surname`,`CName`,`Fathername`,`Birthdate`,`AFM`,`Landline`,`Mobile`,`Address`,`Adressnum`,`Location`,`ZIP`,`Bankaccount`) VALUES ('$Surname','$Name','$Fathername','$Dateofbirth','$Afm','$Landline','$Mobile','$Address','$Addressnum','$Location','$ZIP','$Bankaccount')");
}
```

Comment: Try printing the result of `mysql_error()` to see what the problem is.

Comment: `or exit(mysql_error());`

Comment: More information is needed. Does it output an error? If so what is the error? Have you created a mysql connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Customers` (`Surname`,`CName`,`Fathername`,`Birthdate`,`AFM`,`Landline`,`Mobile`,`Address`,`Adressnum`,`Location`,`ZIP`,`Bankaccount`) VALUES ('$Surname','$Name','$Fathername','$Dateofbirth','$Afm','$Landline','$Mobile','$Address','$Addressnum','$Location',
'$ZIP','$Bankaccount')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Will give you the answer.

And make sure to escape your data:

```
 $Surname=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Surname']);
  $Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Name']);
  $Fathername=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Fathername']);
 [...]
```

Better, use a prepared statement:

```
$q =  $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `Customers` SET `Surname` = ? [...]");
$q->execute( array( $_REQUEST['Surname'], [...] ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, actually the problem was connecting to the database